# Error on data socket server

Tags: python, sockets, server, undefined

I am a beginner in programming with python, and I want to use data socket to send and receive messages in the same machine, so I executed those two script and in the beginning it works but at the end the server return an error:

> NameError: name 'client address' is not defined

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to find what is wrong if you add code.

Comment: You should paste the actual code into the question using the [edit] button rather than use an image of the code.

Comment: I found the solution : it was just one tab in the python code  that generated this error thank you any way :)